# How do I increase memory given to maven-glassfish-plugin?

Tags: maven-2, glassfish, glassfish-3, permgen

I'm using the Maven plugin for embedded Glassfish - here's my plugin declaration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
  <configuration>
    <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After several clicks through my data-intensive web app, I run out of PermGen space.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

I've already configured MAVEN_OPTS to use more memory:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

But it looks like the Java process spawned by `mvn glassfish:run` is only getting about half a gigabyte of memory before it seizes up.

Does the Glassfish plugin have any configuration settings for upping its memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Just to clarify. The permanent generation space contains loaded class objects and interned strings. It is allocated **outside** of the Java heap as illustrated below:

[image]

On recent Sun VMs, the default maximum size is `64m` (i.e. `-XX:MaxPermSize=64m`) and is adequate for most applications (the problem is very likely related to frequent undeploy/redeploy here though). I would anyway try with `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` or `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`, `1024m` seems really oversized!

Answer (score 5):

After further consultation with some colleagues, it seems I was increasing the wrong memory value in Maven.

To increase PermGen space, I added this to my MAVEN_OPTS:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Comment: For those on *nix or OSX, I used export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"